# Breaking links in table column

Tags: tables, formatting, urls, booktabs

I'm using the acm latex template for journals available here: http://www.acm.org/publications/authors/submissions

This follows a one-column format.

In a table, I have three columns. The third column has URLs. But the URLs are overflowing the column. How do I break them?

[image]

```
\documentclass[format=acmsmall, review=false, screen=true]{acmart}
\usepackage{booktabs} % For formal tables
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\title[This is a Title]{This is a title}  
\maketitle

\section{Introduction}
\lipsum[2-8]

\begin{table}[!t]%
\caption{This Table}
\label{table:lexical_features}
\begin{minipage}{\columnwidth}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{V{0.2\linewidth} V{0.5\linewidth} V{0.25\linewidth}}                              
\toprule
Feature Type & Description & Example\\ [0.5ex]
\midrule
Top Level Domain variant URL in blacklist & Checking whether different TLDs of the URL exist in blacklist & www.legitsite.com
www.legitsite.fr
www.legitsite.in etc.
\\
\addlinespace
IP Address Equivalence & URL with similar directory structure to a phishing URL but different domain names, pointing to same IP address & http://www.xyz.com/online.paypal.com and
http://www.abc.com/online.paypal.com both pointing to same IP address
\\
\addlinespace
Query String Substitution & Changing various parameters in URL & http://www.abc.com/online/ebay.php?abc
http://www.abc.com/online/ebay.php?xyz\\
\addlinespace
Nonmatching URLs & Link where text is URL but href attribute is different than the URL & <a href="www.paypal-login.com">https://www.paypal.com</a>\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{minipage}
\end{table}%

\lipsum[9-15]
\end{document}
```

Also I have not put all the rows in the table in the MWE. If I have many rows, the table gets placed at the end of the paper instead of being placed where I want.

Comment: please complete your *mwe* that it will become compilable. missing are columns type definition etc

Comment: @Zarko It is compiling on my machine

Comment: where you have different code :-)  where is defined `V`? . anyway, see my answer. i had problem since i haven't installed  `acmart`, so i consider standard `article`, but i don't know if your table is one or two column type

Comment: @Zarko V is defined in package varwidth

Comment: ok, i didn't use it. sorry for my complains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}%[format=acmsmall, review=false, screen=true]{acmart}
\usepackage[margin=20mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{array, booktabs}

\usepackage{ragged2e}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\RaggedRight}p{#1}}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,linkcolor={blue},citecolor={red},
            breaklinks=true
            ]{hyperref}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
%\title[This is a Title]{This is a title}
%\maketitle

\section{Introduction}
\lipsum[11]

\begin{table}[ht]%
\caption{This Table}
\label{table:lexical_features}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{L{\dimexpr0.2\linewidth-2\tabcolsep}
                L{\dimexpr0.5\linewidth-2\tabcolsep}
                L{\dimexpr0.3\linewidth-2\tabcolsep}
                }
\toprule
Feature Type & Description & Example\\ [0.5ex]
\midrule
Top Level Domain variant URL in blacklist
    & Checking whether different TLDs of the URL exist in blacklist
        &   \url{www.legitsite.com}
            \url{www.legitsite.fr}
            \url{ww.legitsite.in} etc.          \\
    \addlinespace
IP Address Equivalence
    & URL with similar directory structure to a phishing URL but different domain names, pointing to same IP address
        &   \url{http://www.xyz.com/online.paypal.com} and
            \url{http://www.abc.com/online.paypal.com}
            both pointing to same IP address    \\
    \addlinespace
Query String Substitution
    & Changing various parameters in URL
        &   \url{http://www.abc.com/online/ebay.php?abc}
            \url{http://www.abc.com/online/ebay.php?xyz}\\
    \addlinespace
Nonmatching URLs
    & Link where text is URL but href attribute is different than the URL
        &   \url{href="www.paypal-login.com">https://www.paypal.com}\\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}%

\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Comment: Just using \url {} for the links solved the problem.

Comment: @user5155835, your primary problem, yes. however -- by the way -- answer solve determination of the table width ... :-). now i see, that the last `\url` had strange content ... you should check this and correct.